# Command to replace a variable inside angle bracket

Tags: macros

In my current document, I have a lot of angle brackets, which are computed via:

```
\langle a, b \rangle
```

Is there anyway I could create a new command, something in the look of:

```
\newcommand{\dotproduct{ab}}{\langle a, b \rangle}
```

so that I could replace the `a` and `b` by other variables? To be more specific, I would love for that command template to work also for:

```
\dotproduct{cd}, \dotproduct{Q,R}
```

Comment: `\dotproduct{a,b}` seems much easier to parse.

Comment: why not simply `\newcommand\dotproduct[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}` then `\dotproduct{Q}{R}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like your suggestion. If you could turn that into an answer I would accept it happily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard LaTeX syntax would be

```
\newcommand\dotproduct[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}
```

then

```
 \dotproduct{Q}{R}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer the syntax suggested by [@DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559173/command-to-replace-a-variable-inside-angle-bracket#comment1410245_559173).

If you still want your syntax (which is imho unclean) this macro will test whether your argument contains a comma, if so it just uses it as is, if not it will put a comma after the first item of your input.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \dotproduct { m }
  {
    \langle
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { , }
      { #1 }
      { \tl_head:n { #1 } , \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
    \rangle
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\dotproduct{a,b} \dotproduct{cd} \dotproduct{abc}$
\end{document}
```